# Get only date from datetime generated string

Tags: python

I have a timestamp that was created with datetime module and now I need to convert `'2020-10-08T14:52:49.387077+00:00'` into 08/OCT/2020?

Can datetime do this? I have tried strptime but I think the `+00:00` at the end is causing errors.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting string into datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466345/converting-string-into-datetime)

Comment: @msanford I tried with strptime as in the link but it didn't work. As per the answer below, splitting the timestamp string along the "T" would have allowed strptime to work, but I didn't think of doing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`fromisoformat`](https://pypi.org/project/backports-datetime-fromisoformat/)  and [`strftime`](https://strftime.org/) method from `datetime` package in Python `3.7`:

```
from datetime import datetime
time = '2020-10-08T14:52:49.387077+00:00'
new_time = datetime.fromisoformat(time).strftime("%d/%b/%Y")
print(new_time)
```

Or with [`strptime`](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/datetime/strptime):

```
from datetime import datetime
time = '2020-10-08T14:52:49.387077+00:00'
new_time = datetime.strptime(time.split('T')[0], "%Y-%m-%d").strftime("%d/%b/%Y")
print(new_time)
```

**Output**:

```
08/Oct/2020
```